# No output when web scraping using lxml

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying to extract a text from a website

Below is the part of HTML Code

```
</script>
<body onLoad="onLoad()"> 
<input id="batterystatus" value="Charging" type="hidden">
<input id="batterylevel"  value="63%" type="hidden">
<input id="signalstrength" value="Good" type="hidden">
<input id="ulCurrentDataRate" value="19317 bps" type="hidden">
<input id="dlCurrentDataRate" value="4969 bps" type="hidden">
<input id="ConnectionTime" value="00:05:40:47" type="hidden">
<input id="imsi" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX" type="hidden">
<input id="devicemodel" value="JMR540" type="hidden">
<input id="connectedStatus" value="Attached" type="hidden">
<input id="physicalCellId" value="25" type="hidden">
<input id="noOfClient" value="3" type="hidden">
<input id="eutrancellid" value="4058640090041A411" type="hidden">
<div id="divAdminApp" width="100%" align="center">
```

My Python code to get the value is

```
import requests
import lxml.html
html = requests.get('http://192.168.225.1')
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)
batVol = doc.xpath('/input [@id="batterylevel"]')
print('Battery Voltage: ', batVol)
```

by the output I'm getting is blank

```
Output:
Battery Voltage:  []
```

Comment: Are these values in the DOM populated using JavaScript?

Comment: Might want to look into using `bs4.BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Actually, this web is hosted on a portable wifi device and I developed a charging setup that will turn on the charging relay based on the battery level. The above code is form  the home page of the wifi device

Comment: The question was, is the site static (is everything contained in the HTML), or is it dynamic (does it load elements using javascript after the HTML has loaded) ?

Comment: I don't know the wifi device is Jio Wifi so there are different models of the device involved and when the web page is inspected each device has a different network response format. Only the home page has this part of the code as common in all the models

Comment: Also, try removing the whitespace between /input and [@id..]
that is, try the xpath selector `/input[@id="batterylevel"]` instead of `/input [@id="batterylevel"]`

Comment: Actually, there is no space in the original code. It May be happed when copy-pasted.

Comment: @AryaDigital could you upload the whole HTML somewhere so that we can download it and try to solve this? Make sure to remove any identification/personal things.

Comment: Hi I have uploaded the file to my drive https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SWLiJw371Ckuta16zG5RNpnpeA_0AWRZ?usp=sharing

Comment: @AryaDigital i've added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this and it should work

Once you have your `doc` loaded, we can use the `get_element_by_id()` function to get the element that we need, which has an id = 'batterylevel'. This will give you the whole element.

```
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)
required_element = doc.get_element_by_id('batterylevel')
```

> output:`<InputElement 2515c0c39a0 name=None type='hidden'>`

What we need is the value inside that element. We can use `.attrib` to access all the attributes of the element, which gives us a dictionary:

```
print(required_element.attrib)
```

> output: `{'id': 'batterylevel', 'value': '79%', 'type': 'hidden'}`

Now we can just access the `'value'` key inside this dictionary normally to get the battery level:

```
print(required_element.attrib['value'])
```

> output: `'79%'`

**Sidenote**: I see you are using `lxml`, a pretty old library which doesn't support common features like

- finding by css classes/selectors,
- a good `find()` function which allows you to search through the whole HTML and get any specific text/tag/class you're looking for
- rendering the javascript on a page

The last one is quite important since most pages today are dynamic not static, meaning that pages have content generated on-the-fly while loading the page using javascript instead of having them hard-coded into HTML, because the content is also changing every second on sites like social media(Instagram/facebook/etc.), content consumption(youtube/netflix/etc.)

The more commonly used web-scraping libraries these days which support these features are `requests_html`, `BeautifulSoup`, and I suggest you start looking into them.